# How to add a generic "All" value in GXT ComboBox

Tags: gwt, gxt

I have a generic GXT3 ComboBox which display all available values for enums :

```
public static <T extends Enum<T>> ComboBox<T> buildEnumCombo(Class<T> t){

  ListStore<T> listStore=new ListStore<T>(new EnumModelKeyProvider<T>());

  for(T e:t.getEnumConstants()){
    listStore.add(e);
  }

  ComboBox<T> combo= new ComboBox<T>(listStore, new EnumLabelProvider<T>());
  combo.setTriggerAction(ComboBoxCell.TriggerAction.ALL);

  return combo;
}
```

This combo works fine.

**What I need :**  I would like a be able to add a "All" value.

I tried to add "null" in the store and customize the LabelProvider to display "All" for this particular case but it does not work as expected : the combo contains the expected line but it displays an empty text instead of "All" and the line does not have a correct size.

Here is my generic ModelKeyProvider for enums

```
public class EnumModelKeyProvider<T extends Enum> implements ModelKeyProvider<T> {

@Override
public String getKey(T item) {
  if(item==null){
    return null;
  }else{
    return item.name();
  }
}
```

And my generic LabelProvider :

```
public class EnumLabelProvider<T extends Enum<T>> implements LabelProvider<T> {

  @Override
  public String getLabel(T item) {
    if(item==null){
      return "All";
    }else{
      return I18nEnum.i18nEnum(item);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you find solution?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the solution you are looking for, but I solved this but simply setting the emptyText of the ComboBox to "All".

Answer (score 0):

Try SimpleComboBox (tested on gxt 2.2.5)

```
private SimpleComboBox<String> createSimpleComboBox(){      
        SimpleComboBox<String> combo = new SimpleComboBox<String>();

        combo.setTypeAhead(true);
        combo.setTriggerAction(TriggerAction.ALL);
        combo.setEditable(editable);
        combo.setForceSelection(true);
        combo.setTemplate(getComboTemplate());
        return combo;
}

private native String getComboTemplate() /*-{
return  [
'<tpl for=".">',
'<tpl if="value == \'\'">',
'<div class="x-combo-list-item" qtip="N/A" qtitle=""></BR></div>',
'</tpl>',
'<tpl if="value != \'\'">',
'<div class="x-combo-list-item" qtip="{value}" qtitle="">{value}</div>',
  '</tpl>',
'</tpl>'
].join("");
}-*/;

public SimpleComboBox<String> buildComboBox(){
            SimpleComboBox<String> combo = createSimpleComboBox();

            combo.add("");
            List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
            for(T e:t.getEnumConstants()){
                list.add(e.name());
            }
            combo.add(list);
            return combo;
}
```